# Android:Viewing pdf files in our own layout using PdfViewer jar file

Tags: android, pdf, layout

Here i used PdfViewer jar file to Read and View Pdf files from Sdcard.Its workind like a charm. but My question is there any possiblities to view Pdf files in own Layout using Xml files not static into Java files.And i used PdfViewerActivity.java from this project [PdfViwer](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library)

Comment: Thanks for providing the source code for showing pdf...